# Apache Camel route definition in Spring XML and run with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have defined Camel routes in 2 XML files, and would like to run the application using Spring Boot component.

Here is the main code:

```
Object[] sources = {
    "META-INF/spring/propertiesContext.xml",
    "META-INF/spring/concurrent-route-context.xml"
};
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplication(sources).run(args);
CamelSpringBootApplicationController applicationController = applicationContext
    .getBean(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.class);
    applicationController.blockMainThread();
```

However, I got the following error during startup

```
2015-08-19 14:54:04.203 ERROR 13812 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at com.oocl.b2b.camel.spring.boot.test.ConcurrencyTest.testSpringBoot(ConcurrencyTest.java:44)
at com.oocl.b2b.camel.spring.boot.test.ConcurrencyTest.main(ConcurrencyTest.java:29)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 6 common frames omitted
```

If I update my pom.xml by using "spring-boot-starter" instead of "spring-boot-starter-web", I got another exception

```
2015-08-19 15:02:06.930  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.15.2 (CamelContext: concurrent-route-context) started in 1.320 seconds
2015-08-19 15:02:06.932  INFO 4528 --- [           main] c.o.b.c.s.boot.test.ConcurrencyTest      : Started ConcurrencyTest in 2.615 seconds (JVM running for 2.867)
Exception in thread "main" 2015-08-19 15:02:06.933  INFO 4528 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@142f024: startup date [Wed Aug 19 15:02:05 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-08-19 15:02:06.934  INFO 4528 --- [       Thread-1] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.15.2 (CamelContext: concurrent-route-context) is shutting down
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
    at com.oocl.b2b.camel.spring.boot.test.ConcurrencyTest.testSpringBoot(ConcurrencyTest.java:47)
    at com.oocl.b2b.camel.spring.boot.test.ConcurrencyTest.main(ConcurrencyTest.java:30)
2015-08-19 15:02:06.937  INFO 4528 --- [       Thread-1] o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Starting to graceful shutdown 4 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
```

Would anyone please advice if I have made any mis-config?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've found a solution for this yet, but try this for your application class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestSpringBootApplication
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        (new SpringApplication("META-INF/spring/propertiesContext.xml",
                               "META-INF/spring/concurrent-route-context.xml")).run(args);
    }
}
```